# Pattern order sensitivity in grep

Tags: grep

I am running into some very strange behavior with grep, which I cannot figure out. I am trying to filter common words out of a file of words, but grep appears to be ignoring some patterns based on their order.
Here is a minimal example that shows the failure:

Test file:

```
a
foo
an
bar
he
the
```

Result from command: `cat test.txt | fgrep -v -w -e 'an' -e 'the' -e 'a' -e 'he'`

```
foo
bar
```

Result from command: `cat test.txt | fgrep -v -w -e 'a' -e 'an' -e 'he' -e 'the'`

```
foo
an
bar
the
```

I can't find anything that indicates grep should show such order sensitivity, and obviously this is a serious problem when I scale up to a real inputs and filter lists.  My suspicion is that this is actually a bug in the installed version of grep - I am running on MacOS Mavericks, and could not reproduce this bug on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Both return `foo` / `bar` to me with `fgrep (GNU grep) 2.18`.

Comment: Same as fedorqui for me with `GNU grep 2.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered my own question: it's a bug in the version of grep that is distributed by Apple (thanks to fedorui and java10 for the confirmation that this is not expected behavior). The current version distributed by Apple is BSD grep: 2.5.1-FreeBSD.

To work around this problem, install GNU grep.  I recommend doing this with brew:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes; brew install homebrew/dupes/grep
```

This will not replace the native grep (on which who knows what may depend), but installs as 'ggrep', which then behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To expand your own answer, OSX uses BSD grep and Linux uses GNU grep. If you want to permanently replace BSD grep with GNU grep, you can do this:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install homebrew/dupes/grep --default-names
```

Then you can use the "grep" command instead of the "ggrep" command. This is helpful for shell scripts that depend on GNU grep to work correctly.

After issuing the above commands you can test that `grep` is mapped to the GNU executable:

```
which grep
/usr/local/bin/grep
```

I switched entirely to GNU grep (and all of the other core utilities) quite a while back. I program with my mac every day. It has yet to burst into flames :) YMMV.